# Possibility of adding environment variables on Podfile

Tags: cocoapods

Is it possible to add environment variables on `Podfile`s without having to create a custom shell script to replace strings inside my `Podfile`?

Example:

```rb
platform :ios, '10.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://<USERNAME>@bitbucket.org/awesometeamname/ios-private-specs.git'
use_modular_headers!

target 'a-generic-app-name' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'MaybeFirebase'
  pod 'AnotherSDK'
  pod 'AlamofireOfCourse'
  pod 'WhoUsesRxSwiftAnyway'

end
```

The reasoning behind this is that we're using a private pod spec repository that we connect to via ssh, and a developer will have to always Push or manually ignore Pushing the username, is it possible to set this via command line?

My current solution right now is that I have a script that I call instead of calling `pod install` this script does the ff:

- Replace the `<USERNAME>` string
- Call `pod install`

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: @Manikandan we connected to the git via SSH instead

Comment: ok. I will try with SSH. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Remember that you can still use ruby syntax in your `Podfile`. Let's assume you keep the username in env var named `REPO_USERNAME`. Then your file would look like:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://' + ENV['REPO_USERNAME'] + '@bitbucket.org/awesometeamname/ios-private-specs.git'
use_modular_headers!

target 'a-generic-app-name' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'MaybeFirebase'
  pod 'AnotherSDK'
  pod 'AlamofireOfCourse'
  pod 'WhoUsesRxSwiftAnyway'

end
```

**Usage**

```
REPO_USERNAME=Zonily pod install
```

**Bonus**

IMO cleaner solution for your problem would be to use SSH access instead of HTTPS. Then, you can create shared SSH key for your team, or add teammates SSH public keys to the repository, so all of them will have the access. In such case, you'll use the following lines for sources:

```
source 'git@github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'git@bitbucket.org/awesometeamname/ios-private-specs.git'
```

If you believe this could work for you, just browse Bitbucket's docs to see how to use SSH keys with your repository.

Cheers!

Comment: Yeah I've been using SSH keys instead of this old question of mine. But the idea that this is ruby escaped my mind, I should've done this before.

Comment: `REPO_USERNAME=Zonily pod install` is how env variables are passed to the podfile from CLI.

Comment: @NSaran i spent a lot of time searching for the right way to pass environment variables to the podfile until i saw your comment, thank you very much!